# when to use LDAP and when to use PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

One of our client has asked us a question that whether we are using LDAP to synchronize our application to their Active Directory or not. I have checked with our code and there the thing is used is *PrincipalContext* . Could any one please tell me that what is major difference in  using of LDAP and PrincipalContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrincipalContext` is just an abstraction over top of LDAP .....

You cannot use `PrincipalContext` ***or*** LDAP - `PrincipalContext` **is** using LDAP ....